# How to use named gRPC clients with factory

Tags: c#, .net, grpc, grpc-dotnet

Looking at the DI supported for gRPC clients, I was having troubles figuring out how the implementation for named gRPC clients should be made.

The [`Grpc.Net.ClientFactory`](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/1ca4245af8c3fc4cc88eaba750a9b26d5e2db0b7/src/Grpc.Net.ClientFactory) package offers such a functionality to register a **named** gRPC client. All examples I could find, however, directly inject a gRPC client into some class instead of creating it by a specified name with a factory.

There is a `GrpcClientFactory` class from the same package that contains such a function to create a gRPC client based on a given name, however, it is abstract and the default implementation is internal. Unlike the `IHttpClientFactory` it cannot be injected. My question is if it is necessary to create a `GrpcClientFactory` implementation myself in order to use the named gRPC clients functionality or perhaps am I missing something.

Comment: *Every* type can be injected, not just interfaces. The `AddGrpcClient` extension method has overloads that accept a `name` parameter. If you check the [source code](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/master/src/Grpc.Net.ClientFactory/GrpcClientServiceExtensions.cs) you'll see that calling `AddGrpcClient` also registers a `GrpcClientFactory`

Comment: I did check that source code and that is how I expected it to work but I was getting some other DI error. Now that you pointed it out I checked it again and turned out that I was using some mistaken type instead of the correct client. Indeed, it works as expected. Thank you!